# Assigning different ringtone for non-contacts

Tags: contacts, ios, ringtones

I'm using **iOS 9.1** and I want to assign one ringtone for all known contacts and a different one for non-contacts.

I also have another ringtone for a few specific contacts, but in general I want to know if the person who's calling is on my contact list.

**How can this be achieved** without any jailbreaks or the like **?**

I'm also aware that I could just define a ringtone for my entire contacts list. But this is just inconvenient. Every time I add a contact on my Google Account I would have to assign the ringtone on the iPhone.

Comment: There are some things that simply aren't readily possible on iOS, and this sounds like one of them. About the only contact/non-contact thing you can do is Do Not Disturb. Apple would likely suggest that you get an Apple Watch as it would show you who is calling without having to get out your phone.

Comment: Yeah, that's literally what Apple would say. What's the thing with Do not Disturb?

Comment: You can set DND to block all calls originating from phone numbers that aren't in your contacts.

Comment: That's not what I want at all. But if I had to define a different ringtone for my entire contact list, then I choose not to.

Answer (score 2):

I have assigned the same ringtone to everyone in my contact list, and it took days. Then I selected a different default ringtone, and I know that when I hear this, the caller is not a contact. But I would suggest adding this feature for iPhone 7, because it's important.

Comment: Yes it's a valid solution, it's also a rather large pain. And when one of the iOS updates installed it erased all the assigned ringtones and I had to do it again.

Comment: Assigning a ringtone to the entire contact list and using the default for the non-contacts is what I described in my answer. I know about this method and I strongly dislike it for obvious reasons. Also suggesting iOS features on a Q&A board is not something Apple will pick up.

Comment: I think making it a feature is a much more logical solution.

Comment: Hum, where will Apple pick it up?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. But "suggesting" this feature here on StackExchange is about equal to liking something on Facebook and expecting it to do good or change something. Off topic, but the only comparison I can think of. And honestly I don't know where to suggest features to big companies. From what I've experienced, they are not heard unless they are very loud, i.e. coming from tons and tons of users.

Comment: Everybody interested should go where Apple will pick this up and suggest this feature, please.

Comment: I was looking for the solution when I came to this board, I figured I must of missed something, it had to be in the phone somewhere, so I added that while agreeing with you. Perhaps a lot of people will see it, perhaps Apple will see it. Perhaps I will kill a ringtone on Facebook and nobody will care, or everybody will get their panties in a bunch. You never know.

Comment: Assuming most people here consider themselves as "power users", the vast majority of users prefer much less features in favor for easy use. Implementing this feature aswell as lots and lots of other features, some users would like would make iOS harder to use for normal users. So most likely Apple will only implement features that are requested a lot, because there are hundreds of features which are requested only by *some* users. Implementing them all would bloat iOS indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't setting the default ringtone to "unknown contact ringtone" and assigning every single contact your "known contact ringtone" be a valid solution...? :)

Comment: Of coruse it would. It's not like I didn't think about that, but it's a bad solution. Every time I add a Contact on Google Contacts, I would have to remember to assign the ringtone...

Comment: I've 2,000+ contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but can offer a partial solution.

Install the Hiya app which blocks spam and telemarketers. Contracts are not blocked. It takes a couple of rings' time for it to do the lookup of unknown numbers and block the bad call.

Create a ringtone that is about 3 seconds of silence at the beginning.

If a call comes in your phone won't make a sound initially. If the call becomes blocked by Hiya you won't hear it at all.

But if the call is not blocked you'll then hear the rest of your ringtone play.

Not a perfect solution since you don't know a legitimate call is coming in until x-second late. And it doesn't address the vibrate function.